# Доступ к вложенному шаблонному типу не шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Имею следующую (абстрактную !!!) структуру:

1. Шаблонный класс, с двумя параметрами. Первый параметр - это тип хранимых данных, второй - аллокатор, который имеет значение по-умолчанию. Также, класс имеет метод, который в качестве аргумента принимает аллокатор.
   *(container)*
2. Следующий класс - обертка над аллокатором, хранит в себе вложенную структуру, которая определяет псевдоним аллокатора. *(allocator)*
3. Заключительный класс - класс самого аллокатора. *(_alloc)*

Код:

```
template <class T>
class _alloc
{

};

struct allocator
{
    template<class T>
    struct helper_allocator
    {
        typedef _alloc<T> hlp_allocator;
    };

};

template <class T, class all = allocator>
class container
{
public:
    void replace_allocator(const all::helper_allocator<T>::hlp_allocator& a)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    allocator::helper_allocator<int>::hlp_allocator a;
    container<int, allocator> t;
    t.replace_allocator(a);
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции получаю ошибку `syntax error: identifier 'helper_allocator'` в методе `replace_allocator` класса `container`. Объясните, где я недопонимаю? Если использовать вместо параметра шаблона all напрямую тип allocator, то компиляция успешна.

P.S.:
using не применимо, т.к. C++ 11 недоступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто [`typename` поставить](https://godbolt.org/z/vP7j8r):

```
template <class T>
class _alloc
{

};

struct allocator
{
    template<class T>
    struct helper_allocator
    {
        typedef _alloc<T> hlp_allocator;
    };

};

template <class T, class all = allocator>
class container
{
public:
    void replace_allocator(const typename all::helper_allocator<T>::hlp_allocator& a)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    allocator::helper_allocator<int>::hlp_allocator a;
    container<int, allocator> t;
    t.replace_allocator(a);
    return 0;
}
```

И лучше не использовать в глобальном скопе идентификаторы, начинающиеся с `_`, потому что они считаются зарезервированными

Comment: @user7860670 [the identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers)

Comment: Честно говоря, я использовал typename, но теперь я получаю иные ошибки:
1) unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
2) syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
3) syntax error: missing ')' before '<'
4) syntax error: '<'
5) syntax error: ')'
6) 'hlp_allocator': is not a member of '`global namespace''

Comment: @Range я же ссылку дал, где всё компилируется, задайте новый вопрос с [mre] или дайте ссылку на godbolt с кодом, который не компилируется

Comment: @dIm0n я разобрался, спасибо Вам. Дело в том, что в проекте поддерживаются два компилятора: bcc32(и 64) и msvc. Так вот, bcc спокойно проглатывал такую конструкцию, а вот msvc никак. В msvs есть доступ к c++ 14 и выше, так что было решение переписать для него под новые стандарты. Спасибо больше за разъяснение.

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Answer (score 1):

Структура `helper_allocator` определена только для `allocator`. Для любой другой сущности она не существует, поэтому для какого то типа `all`она тоже не существует, потому что `all` только по умолчанию есть `allocator`, но он может быть и другим типом. А раз может, значит синтаксис не верный. Другое дело, если вы  определите `all` как псевдоним  типа `allocator`, тогда компилятору будет известно, что это только  один тип, в котором определен  искомый тип:  `using all = allocator;` Или же к зависимой  имени `helper_allocator<t>`нужно обращаться только через `allocator`